# Can I call /sbin/init from init script

Tags: shell, init

Let us say I have a custom init like this

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sleep infinity
```

Which of these will load init

1. ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   /sbin/init
   sleep infinity
   ```
2. ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   exec /sbin/init
   sleep infinity
   ```

I know that exec is supposed to start a new shell but is it necessary?

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `!` character from the first line of the script.  `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: thanks that's just an oversight

Comment: "_I know that exec is supposed to start a new shell_" - no, it replaces the current process with the named one. Crucially in this context, the PID remains unchanged

Comment: The `exec` shell command dose not call `exec`, it skips `fork`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is actually very normal to invoke `init` from a script.  Common bootloader scripts will properly mount the root disk and then run init.
2. To invoke `init` as init, and not as `telinit`, it must be run as PID 1.   Thus you need the `exec`.  Thus, only your (2) script is potentially useful to run init.
3. After an `exec`, the script is no longer running.  Thus, the `sleep infinity` will not run.  Anything run before the exec can be quite useful.
4. If you just want something else running, you might want to just list it appropriately in `/etc/inittab`, or a script invoked from there (typically placed in `/etc/init.d` and symlinked into `/etc/rc`*#*`.d`).